# Cannot mark Excel workbook as Final

Tags: vb.net, excel

The situation is as follows:

We want to publish to a remote machine a locally edited file. This file could be of type Word, Excel, Powerpoint. Apparently, after the publishing to the remote machine, we would like the local document to be marked as final, in order to prevent the user from editing it again (, because the intented workflow is first downloading it from the remote server, editing the downloaded document and the publishing it back to the server).

So, there is a bunch of code like this:

```
Public Sub setDocFinal()
Select Case addin.HostType
    Case ADXOfficeHostApp.ohaWord
        Dim doc As Word.Document = Nothing
        Try
            doc = addin.WordApp.ActiveDocument
            doc.Final = True
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw New Exception(Me.addin.getLabel("cannotSaveCopy", "Cannot Save the document."))
        Finally
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(doc)
        End Try
    Case ADXOfficeHostApp.ohaExcel
        Dim doc As Excel.Workbook = Nothing
        Try
            doc = addin.ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook

            doc.Final = True
            'doc.RefreshAll()
            'doc.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone()
            'doc.Calculate()

        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw New Exception(Me.addin.getLabel("cannotSaveCopy", "Cannot Save the document."))
        Finally
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(doc)
        End Try
    ' Powerpoint case intentionally skipped as is has same format/code
End Select
End Sub
```

The above code works pretty well for the Word case, but when it comes to Excel, it stacks on the popup which informs the user for the publish action to the remote server: 
[image]

**EDIT**
At that particular point, the execution freezes (or maybe gets into an infinite internal loop, because the only available buttons in debugging mode are pause and stop) at the line of setting the document as final and it never reaches the `finally` statement (where we release the object). It also seems like the execution tries to return control back to the excel document, but nothing more than this notification occurs :

[image]

Any idea of what is wrong in the above code, regarding the handling of Excel?

*The lines in comments display some trials I have been going through, while trying to find a solution around the net.*

In addition, here is also the popup's related code:

```
Private Sub doWork(ByVal action As String, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs)
    Dim myDoc As MyDocument
    myDoc = DirectCast(e.Argument, MyDocument)
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Post in Thread")

    Dim resultObject(3) As Object
    resultObject(0) = True
    resultObject(1) = myDoc

    Dim saveDocumentResult As SaveDocumentResult = Nothing
    Try
        Select Case action
            Case Constants.SAVE_DRAFT
                saveDocumentResult = myDoc.getRequestService().saveDraft(myDoc.getSaveFile(), myDoc.getDocName(), myDoc)
            Case Constants.PUBLISH
                saveDocumentResult = myDoc.getRequestService().publishDocument(myDoc.getSaveFile(), myDoc.getDocName(), myDoc)
                myDoc.setDocFinal() 'this line makes the call to the above code
        End Select

        myDoc.updateDocumentProperty(Constants.VERSION, saveDocumentResult.version)
        myDoc.updateDocumentProperty(Constants.HASH, saveDocumentResult.hash)

        myDoc.setSaved(True)
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500)
    Catch ex As Exception
        resultObject(0) = False
        resultObject(2) = ex.Message
    Finally
        e.Result = resultObject
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried to step through the code? Does it reach `Marshal.ReleaseComObject(doc)`? I would also like to see the code for the Popup before and after this piece of code